# Weird error when calling document.GetElementsByTagName("head")

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I have an application that uses the following code to inject JavaScript in a web page in a `WebBrowser`:

```
HtmlElement head = document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = document.CreateElement("script"); 
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement; 
element.text = CurrentFuncs; 
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

But I just got an error report from a customer that got an exception in the `document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0]` piece of code that says: "Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1." I'm pretty sure that's from the `[0]` thing in that line of code, but no idea why.

I assume is because there is no "head" element. I just uploaded a page with no head and opened it with my application, but the error didn't reproduce. The `WebBrowser` automatically adds the "head" element. I even tried uploading a ".txt" file and still no error. Any idea why could this be happening or how could I reproduce the error?

Unfortunately I don't know on which web page the error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your code looks like this:

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement head = document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = document.CreateElement("script");
mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "alert('1');";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

The problem is that straight after Navigate, the document isn't loaded yet. You will need to  move the part of the code that access the document into the DocumentCompleted handler.

```
private void Go()
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    string url = "http://www.google.com";
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
}
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement head = document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    HtmlElement scriptEl = document.CreateElement("script");
    mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
    element.text = "alert('1');";
    head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
    // Code here
}
```

Comment: Is not. The code runs after the page loads. But yes, I think it might be related to this.