# Get all <img> elements on a webpage

Tags: c#

Hey guys I was wondering how to get all  elements with C# on a webpage. I was using this code below:

```
HtmlElementCollection collection = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");

foreach(HtmlElement element in collection) {
  //do my stuff with iterations
}
```

However that code pops up with this error:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

How would I go about doing this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint before the `foreach`. Then inspect the types in `collection`.

I suspect it probably wants some base class of `HtmlElement` .

Alternatively:

```
HtmlElementCollection collection = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");

foreach(object e in collection) {
  //do my stuff with iterations
  var element = e as HtmlElement;
  if (element == null)
       Debug.Print("Type of e: {0}", e.GetType);
  else
  {
  // ok
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: He means that you should step through the code while in debugging mode and look what type your collection is. Might help to clearify, if you get an empty collection from 'GetElementsByTagName' or if this works out as expected. The type of the Objects should be alright, as stated in the MSDN.

Comment: @leppie: Just added the output for the collectionSize.

Comment: @chiffre: That is irrelevant. `foreach` wont go 'out of bounds'.

Comment: @leppie: It's not irrelevant, as it is not sure, that the whole collection is not 'null'. At least not irrelevant for finding the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your Document has finished loading, e. g. this code snippet

```
private void DisplayMetaDescription()
{
    if (webBrowser1.Document != null) //the statement!
    {
      HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("META");
      foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
        {
          //Some loop-stuff you propably want to do
        }
    }
}
```

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx) does this in the if-statement.

Also this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321235/weird-error-when-calling-document-getelementsbytagnamehead) might be related.

Comment: If with a statement checking if the document has loaded, it still returns the same error.

Comment: I think I found my problem. I believe it had something to do with where I was initializing the HtmlElementCollection.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `var` instead of `HtmlElement`:

```
var collection = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");

foreach(var element in collection) {
  //do my stuff with iterations
}
```

Then you can hover the mouse in Visual Studio on `var` and you will se the real type which the iterator returns.

best regards!

Comment: He doesn't need to use var, as in the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx) is clearly stated, that 'GetElementsByTagName' returns a 'HtmlElementCollection'.

Comment: -1: HtmlElementCollection is not generic, hence `var` will be `object` and pretty much useless for the purpose of the question.

Comment: I have provided a generic scenario to investigate the problem. You are right that var can not give good results.